# WNDR4500 DHCP passthrough not working

Tags: router, dhcp

I have a 2Wire Internet gateway with DHCP running. I have added a NetGear WNDR4500 to provide Wireless N and network attached storage (USB via WNDR4500). I have a media server connected to the 2Wire and I have a client on the Wireless N, which cannot access the media server since on a different subnet (10.x.x.x vs. 192.x.x.x).

I tried turning off the "Use router as DHCP Server" but now I cannot get the clients connected to the WNDR4500 to get any IP address.

Is it possible to have a client connected to WNDR4500 obtain DHCP from the 2Wire? Or is this an invalid connection?

**Steps taken:**

1. Assigned static IP on 2Wire for WNDR4500 mac address
2. Unchecked "Use router as DHCP Server" on WNDR4500 LAN Setup (Advanced)
3. Power cycled WNDR4500

**Results:**

1. WNDR4500 shows IP address as assigned
2. LAN Setup shows IP Address as 10.0.0.1 (not sure what this means - unable to change to value in the 2Wire range without getting WAN Subnet conflict error)

Comment: Can you describe how the routers connect together (maybe a diagram)?

Comment: The problems probably relate to the routers being on different networks.  Why disable the WAN (and DHCP) side of the WNDR4500, reset its IP address to the same range as the 2Wire and connect the LAN port to the 2WIRE - in that way you are using the WNDR4500 as a bridge rather then a router, and don't need to worry about complex DHCP setups which are probably not supported by your hardware anyway.

Comment: Thanks davidgo, the solution to make it work is to disconnect the cable from the "Internet Port" and connect to one of the four LAN ports. However the flaw in this design is I loose the SAN capability of the device; the "Readyshare" features are unaccessible.

Comment: As I indicated you will need to change the IP address on your WNDR4500 to be in the same range as your 2Wire device for this to work.

Comment: I am not understanding. Are you saying it is possible to have the WNDR4500 be a client of the 2Wire router AND provide ReadyShare services? I am not understanding how to get the WNDR4500 to "be in the same range" of the 2Wire... I try to specify the WNDR4500 to be in the same range and I get a WAN range conflict. Do you know what setting I need to change?

Comment: Additional info: Once I disconnect the cable between the routers from the WNDR4500 "Internet Port" to a LAN port I do get DHCP for my WNDR4500 wired & wireless connected devices, however, I am unable to access the administration interface on the WNDR4500 or access the USB attached storage (readyshare). I believe the problem lies with the values on the "Internet" tab and the LAN IP values on the LAN tab. I can't have the same subnet based IP number in both tabs.

Comment: If you provide a diagram with your LAN/WAN layout including IP addresses and devices, I believe I will be able to answer your query.   I do not have a WNDR4500 or a 2Wire router, but I am familiar with these classes of devices generally, and yes, I believe the WNDR4500 can be a client of the 2Wire Router and provide Filesharing Services (Readyshare is, from what i understand just file sharing using Microsofts SMB/CIFS protocol).